# SSIS Error: Disconnected recordsets are not available from ODBC connections

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, execute-sql-task, mysql-odbc-connector

I have one ***EXECUTE SQL TASK***  in SSIS package ,

**Task Type**: Execute SQL TASK
**Data Source Type:** ODBC for MySql (DSN)

Error :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "select  *  from
> nasb_dev.v_borrower_address" failed with the following error:
> "Disconnected recordsets are not available from ODBC connections.".
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
> property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
> connection not established correctly.

it works fine with OLEDB..

any suggestion ?

Comment: This is apparently a long-standing bug in SSIS and/or ODBC.  See the answer in this post for a possible workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637776/insert-two-variables-to-object-in-ssis